# Change where mlocate stores the database?

Tags: arch-linux, locate

Looks like it's not configurable through `/etc/updatedb.conf`, and not mentioned in its manual as well.

So can I change that?

Comment: Which distrib? What have you tried? Did you read `/usr/share/doc`?

Comment: @F.Hauri only read `man update.conf`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably know that `mlocate` only does queries on the databases created by `updatedb`. If you want to change the default location of the databases created by `updatedb` you should pass the `--output FILE` option to `updatedb` and then do the query with `locate --database FILE` afterwards.

You could do:

```
$ sudo updatedb -o /var/db/foo.db
$ locate -d /var/db/foo.db something
```